# How to insert value into a SQL Server table by getting value and column name from another table

Tags: sql-server

```
create table T1
(
    Name varchar(50),
    Address varchar(50),
    Tel varchar(50)
);

create table T2
(
    ParamName varchar(50),
    ParamValue Varchar(60),
    TableName varchar(50)
);

insert into T2 values('Name', 'test', 'Member');
insert into T2 values('Address', 'testAdd', 'Member');
insert into T2 values('Tel', 'test', 'Member');

insert into T1(Select distinct ParamName from T2) 
values(select ParamValue from T2 )
```

I'm looking for a way to do a insertion to T1 table by getting value and column name from T2 table.need to get column name from T2 table and Value to that particular column

Comment: Can you tell us what is the logical _relation_ between the two tables?  This looks like possibly bad design to me.

Comment: This doesnt look like a proper use of databases. It looks like you are using table T2 to temporary store values, which are irrelevant to each other. column ParamValue migh hold a name and on the next row hold a phone number. doesnt seem right. you should make the insertion to T1 directly from the source of your data

Comment: T1 column Name  = T2 ParmName this is just only sample table

insert into T1(Select distinct ParamName from T2) 
values(select ParamValue from T2 )

Comment: I dont think I understood exactly what you are trying to accomplish here. post an sample of what do you want T1 to hold after the insertion

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TableName varchar(50) = 'T1'
DECLARE @ColumnName varchar(MAX)
SELECT @ColumnName= coalesce(@ColumnName + ', ', '') + a.COLUMN_NAME
from (SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    inner join T2 on TableName = TABLE_NAME
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName and ParamName = COLUMN_NAME) a;
print @ColumnName

declare @ParamName varchar(MAX)
SELECT @ParamName = coalesce(@ParamName + ', ', '') + ''''+a.ParamValue+''''
from (SELECT COLUMN_NAME,ParamValue
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    inner join T2 on TableName = TABLE_NAME
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName and ParamName = COLUMN_NAME) a;
print @ParamName

declare @QUERY nvarchar(MAX);
SET @QUERY = 'INSERT INTO T1 ('+@ColumnName+')
          VALUES ('+@ParamName+')'

EXEC sp_executesql @QUERY
```

this is the answer what i expect ,thanks all for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
INSERT INTO T2(Column1,Column2)
SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM T1 
GROUP BY Column1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a pivot query on `T2` to get the names, addresses, and telephone numbers onto a single row for each table name.  Then, just do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` as you were, except use the pivoted result.

```
INSERT INTO T1 (Name, Address, Tel)
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN ParamName = 'Name'    THEN ParamValue END) AS Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ParamName = 'Address' THEN ParamValue END) AS Address,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ParamName = 'Tel'     THEN ParamValue END) AS Tel
FROM T2
GROUP BY TableName
-- WHERE TableName IN ('Member', ...)
```

You can uncomment the `WHERE` clause if you want to restrict the insert to certain table names.

As a general comment, if you are doing this to get your data into a more normalized form, then I think it is good.  But if you plan on storing your data like this long term, you might want to reconsider your table design.

Comment: in t2 table ParamName is the Column Name and Paramvalue is the Value for that Column,i want get both from T2 table.are there way to do that

Answer (score 1):

Your table structure doesn't make much sense. There is no obvious logical relation between the tables. Is the second one just a buffer table?

In any case however, if you want to insert values from a table into another table you do it like that:

```
INSERT INTO [target_table] ([target_column_1], [target_column_2], ..., [target_column_n])
    SELECT [source_column_1], [source_column_2], ..., [source_column_n]
        FROM [source_table] 
        WHERE [conditon]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking like..

```
INSERT INTO T1(Name) 
SELECT DISTINCT ParamName FROM T2
```

Comment: in t2 table ParamName is the Column Name and Paramvalue is the Value for that Column,i want get both from T2 table.are there way to do that